# How to remove the outer frame's color of a Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I use ListBox in my wpf application. The code is as below.
In the ListBox's ItemTemplate a Button is there.

When I use mouse to hover on each button, there is nearly blue color on the button's **outer frame (not the inner part)**. As you can see, I mark it with a red line.
I don't know how to remove it or make it to be parent.

I put my demo code to Github:
https://github.com/tomxue/RemoveColor2.git

[image]

```
       <ListBox Name="ListBox" 
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 Background="#40475F"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                 Margin="0,9,0,0" 
                 Width="336"
                 Height="492"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"                      
                 ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent">
                    <Button Name="ItemButton"  BorderThickness="0" Padding="-2" Background="#40475F" Margin="0" Height="50">
                    </Button>

                    <Border Width="360" Margin="-10,0,-10,0" Height="1" Background="#383F55"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: You need to set ListBox.ItemContainerStyle to be applied to ListBoxItem which hosts StackPanel in ListBox.ItemTemplate.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved by your answer.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these two fields:

```
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 0 0"/>
```

Messing with the BorderBrush or BorderThickness should remove the border. I just copied these from XAML, obviously just use the values BorderBrush and BorderThickness

Comment: Thanks! I use your code, but the outer frame line still exists. I commit the code to my Github, you could check the link I provide in the main post.